# Modifying OpenGL FBO texture attachment in CUDA

Tags: opengl, cuda

I have the following scenario:

I have custom FBO with texture as color attachment.I render my stuff into that FBO.Next step I need to share that texture with CUDA and then run on it some post-processing kernel.Afterwards  the texture should be bound back to a full screen quad and rendered to default Frame Buffer.
I have read [several OpenGL / CUDA interop tutorials](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/Graphics_Interop.html) and some of the steps of doing this are not completely clear to me.

First ,what I see they usually do is to read data from GL texture X ,process it in CUDA ,and then using PBO fill texture Y with resulting data.

Another thing I noticed (correct me if I am wrong) is that the OpenGL in those demos use PBO bound by default and that means that the first pass rendering results are stored into it? I am really unsure about it as all those demos use fixed OpenGL and I see no place where PBO is bound when the initial geometry pass is rendered.

So back to  my case:
My final question is-can I operate directly on OpenGL texture in CUDA without using PBO so that I can modify it in CUDA kernel? 
If no , then does it mean I have to pack FBO texture into PBO before passing it to CUDA stage?

**UPDATE:**

Filling PBO from Frame buffer is usually done using glReadPixels(), which means it is downloaded to CPU.That is something I want to prevent.  - THAT WAS WRONG ASSUMPTION. So based on the fact I can fill PBO with pixels from texture is the following way to go?  :
Fill PBO with data from texture.

Map it to CUDA buffer resource.

Do changes to the data with a kernel.

Update target texture from  modified PBO.

Use the updated texture in OpenGL  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of processing an "OpenGL Texture" in CUDA and then immediately using it in OpenGL with no additional overhead:

https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st

Comment: this appears to be offline now, but I found this which might be the same thing? Some very useful info in here, even though it's very old CUDA:

https://github.dev/Hello100blog/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st

Comment: is it able to Direct write to OpenGL default BackBuffer's ColorAttachment(GL_BACK) by CUDA from kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

> Filling PBO from Frame buffer is usually done using glReadPixels(), which means it is downloaded to CPU.That is something I want to prevent.

Wrong!

glReadPixels into a PBO is carried out completely on the GPU and does not do a roundtrip to system memory.

#### Update:

There are several constraints on CUDA-graphics interop. For example you can not map a graphics resource to CUDA memory while its being bound in the graphics context; specifically you can map it, but any access to it yields undefined results. Hence the usual strategy employs a proxy object.

So using a PBO as intermediary from OpenGL to CUDA is a worthwile method if the OpenGL resource in question can not be unbound for whatever reason. However in the case of FBOs it doesn't really matter, as whatever is bound to a FBO can not be used as a data source as long as it's bound. Due to that limitation there are normally several instances of target objects (renderbuffer or textures) present, used round robin in a multibuffer fashion.

So either you copy it, or you unbind it before mapping it in CUDA. With multiple buffers the latter is the preferred method.

When using CUDA textures you should always write to a different texture as you're reading from (in the case of textures you'd have to bind them to CUDA surfaces).

Comment: Do you mean I have to detach the texture from FBO before mapping it to CUDA resource?

Comment: @MichaelIV: Either that or unbind the FBO itself; ideally you do both. The CUDA documentation is a bit unclear what is meant by "a graphics resource being in use". Best to not take any chances and get into a definite state.

Comment: take a look at my recent post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188522/cuda-opengl-interop-post-processing-sample-issues

Comment: You can have GPU resources bound to both CUDA and OpenGL simultaneously. You don't have to unbind anything, please refer to this example:
https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st

Comment: is it able to Direct write to OpenGL default BackBuffer's ColorAttachment(GL_BACK) by CUDA from kernel ?

Comment: @gpu double buffering only exists for the window default framebuffers. The way OpenGL was constructed the window default framebuffer isn't owned by the OpenGL implementation, has not associated OpenGL object and hence can't imported into CUDA. However these days there's kind of a roundabout way to implement a kludge that'd have this effect: Create a Vulkan instance, with WSI on the window, create a swap chain, the images of which you can then export via a system handle, re-import to OpenGL and then import that into CUDA. Take note: Such a Rube-Goldberg is possible, but I never implemented it.