# Trasfer data from a PBO to a VBO

Tags: opengl

I been trying to wrap my head around trasnfering data from my FBO to a PBO to a texture to render it to a QUAD:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorAttachment0, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthAttachment);
```

To my PBO:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObj);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferObj);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 800 * 800 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

But I try to transfer it like this: (*which is where the **ISSUE IS** *) .. my guess

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, bufferObj);
glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

I have code that renders out a PBO from CUDA .. transfers it to a texture, and it displays it correctly
And I can render out my FBO by rendering its texture to a quad as well

The issue is the transferring between the FBO to the PBO it seems to to function correctly, since when I replace the render FBO->PBO code it does not work correctly

Comment: Why do you need a PBO at all?

Comment: Pixel unpacking happens with glTexImage. glReadPixels *packs* pixels and needs a GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, but you create a GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER. However why do you want to use a PBO in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to get the screen render into CUDA so I can do a bunch of operations on it .. ie a bunch of image filters for a project here at work. It seems you cannnot really pass an FBO directly into CUDA but you can pass a PBO

Comment: May be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053444/modifying-opengl-fbo-texture-attachment-in-cuda

Comment: And this one should help for sure http://3dgep.com/opengl-interoperability-with-cuda/

Answer (score -2):

Some things to try:

- Make sure that your FBO is still bound when you do the ReadPixels.
- Check that glGetError isn't reporting any errors.
- Try reading to a buffer (regular C array) instead of binding the PBO and see if it seems to be getting filled in with correct values.

Comment: Don't use an answer to post a bunch of questions for clarification.  Use the comments for that.

Comment: Yeah how do I down vote Robert Crovella he has made himself some kind of self imposed manager ... sorry Robert we are not as awesome as you jeez...